# react-native-video does not add Authorization header for iOS, works on Android

Tags: react-native, avplayer, react-native-video

I am having issue with react-native-video where Authorization headers is not being to the source on iOS while its working on android devices.

My videos are private and stored in Azure Media Services which can be accessed through authorization token.
react-native-video version - 5.2.0

Below is my implementation

```
<Video
    ref={player}
    width={width}
    style={styles.backgroundVideo}
    onError={e = {
        console.log('EE', e);
    }}
    progressUpdateInterval={10000}
    onEnd={() = {
        checkCompletion();
    }}
    resizeMode={'contain'}
    source={{
        uri: 'https://mediaservice-inct.streaming.media.azure.net/.../...ism/manifest(format=m3u8-cmaf,encryption=cbc)',
        type: 'm3u8',
        headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer [TOKEN]'}
    }}
    controls={true}
    pictureInPicture={true}
    onLoad={(data) = console.log('on load', data)}
/>
```

This works in Android but fails on iOS where the server complains about there being no Authorization header in the request.

I don't get it, any ideas?